# CALCULATE measure in calculated table

Tags: powerbi, dax

This works perfectly if `TableB` is a physical table:

```
Measure=
CALCULATE([Measure], TableA[ID] IN VALUES(TableB[ID]))
```

But, how to calculate the same measure in an **intermediate** table?

```
Measure=
VAR Tab = FILTER(...)
RETURN
CALCULATE([Measure], TableA[ID] IN VALUES(Tab[ID]))
```

This doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMMARIZE` to retrieve a unique list of values.

For example

```
Measure=
VAR Tab = SUMMARIZE(FILTER(...), [ID])
RETURN
CALCULATE([Measure], FILTER(TableA, TableA[ID] IN Tab))
```